# how to select the value on ddl when page is load

Tags: asp.net

on my server side i have Label2.Text = "20" when my page is load how to select the ddl value 20?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDis" runat="server" Width="80px" onchange="CalculateCost();">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0">0%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="15">15%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="20">20%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="25">25%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="30">30%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="35">35%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="40">40%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="45">45%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="50">50%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="55">55%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="60">60%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="65">65%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="70">70%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="75">75%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="80">80%</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select it with a manual value:

```
ddlDis.SelectedValue = "20";
```

And from your textbox:

```
ddlDis.SelectedValue = Label2.Text;
```

Read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ddlDis.SelectedValue = "Label2.text.value";?